# How to generate a running weighted average in google sheets using arrayformula that handles blank rows performantly?

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I need to maintain around a dozen sheets where we want to have a running weighted average, with weights that decay over time:

|  | *A* | *B* | *C* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *1* | **Values** | **Weights** | **AVG** |
| *2* | 6 | 29.63% | 6 |
| *3* | 3 | 44.44% | 4.2 |
| *4* | 2 | 66.67% | 3.16 |
| *5* | 4 | 100.00% | 3.51 |

Values is pulled from another sheet, based on a filter.

Weights is generated by raising a percent to the power of the row:

- `B5 = (2/3)^0`
- `B4 = (2/3)^1`
- `B3 = (2/3)^2`
- `B2 = (2/3)^4`

The (simplified) code is `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="","",POW($D$1,$D$2-(ROW(A2:A)-1))` where D1 = 2/3 and D2 = COUNT(A2:A))

My trouble comes with the weighted avg. It's a pretty easy formula when it doesn't automatically expand: `=AVERAGE.WEIGHTED(A$2:A2, B$2:B2)`. The problem is that I have to drag this formula down, every time a value is added. What I'd like to do, is similar to the weights formula, is to transform it into an arrayformula.

###### What I've attempt so far

I know that `AVERAGE.WEIGHTED(values, weights)` is just a shorthand for `SUMPRODUCT(values, weights)/sum(weights)` and that is just a shorthand for `=MMULT(TRANSPOSE(values), weights)/SUM(weights)`

I figure out that generating a matrix using `ROW()<=TRANSPOSE(ROW())`, I can get the weight average in an arrayformula:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="", "", MMULT(
    TRANSPOSE((ROW(A2:A5)<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(A2:A5))) * IF(A2:A5="",0,A2:A5)),
    B2:B5
)/MMULT(
    (ROW(B2:B5)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(B2:B5))) * 1,
    B2:B5
)))
```

It's so close, as it prints out the weighted average! Unfortunately it has two problems:

1. It cannot handle blank values. I tried adjusting `A2:A5` to be `IF(A2:A5="",0,A2:A5)` and the same for B2:B5, but it did not work. It just gave the error "Function MMULT parameter 2 expects number values. But '' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number."
2. It cannot be made to auto expand by dropping the `5` from the references so that they are column references. The spreadsheet slows down to a crawl. I'm quite sure that's because `ROW()<=TRANSPOSE(ROW())` is taking the 1000 blank rows and generating 1000*1000 = a million cell matrix. I tried adding `FILTER()` but that's incompatible with `ROW()` (as far as I can tell). I'm hoping the answer to 1 is the same answer as 2, as the extra blank cells seem to be the source of both problems.

How can I fix the blank cell problem, and make my arrayformula efficient? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`MAP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985) function can be used to simulate a dragdown formula using a single formula. For example, to turn this into a single formula

```cpp
=AVERAGE.WEIGHTED(A$2:A2, B$2:B2)
```

You can use

```cpp
=MAP(A2:A,B2:B,LAMBDA(value,weight,AVERAGE.WEIGHTED(A2:value,B2:weight)))
```

To return an empty cell if the value or the weight is blank, use

```cpp
=MAP(A2:A,B2:B,LAMBDA(value,weight,IF(OR(value="",weight=""),,AVERAGE.WEIGHTED(A2:value,B2:weight))))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's a lot easier than how I was trying to achieve it. Thank you!